# How to divide the PUL or DIR (stepper driver) signal into multiple equal signals

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm, stepper-motor, buffer

My problem concerns the synchronization of two stepper motors that control the movement of the Y axis.
I built a 3-axis CNC machine that uses two stepper motors for the Y axis.
The controller sends the signal to the driver (DM556T) which in turn sends 4 digital signals to the single motor (PUL+, PUL-, DIR+, DIR-).
The two motors must be synchronized, and therefore move in the same way.
Synchronization is currently done by the controller (DDCS v4.1).

[image: Current scheme]

Using this approach, to synchronize two motors via the controller, I am going to use 8 pins on the controller (2x PUL+, 2x PUL-, 2x DIR+, 2x DIR-).

So I thought I'd do something different:

[image: Scheme I would like to make]

I therefore need an active electronic device that has one of the 4 signals as input (PUL+, PUL-, DIR+, DIR-) and as output 2 signals completely equal to the input signal.
So I need a signal splitter (I think that's what it's called).

I was advised to use an OPERATIONAL BUFFER (unit gain).
Here's a diagram that might work:

[image: Operational buffer]

Do you think this is the right scheme?
Are there other solutions?

Comment: What happens if the motors get out of sync?

Comment: If the engines are not synchronized, the gantry can twist and risk breaking everything.

Comment: `I was advised to use an OPERATIONAL BUFFER (unit gain).` Advised by whom/with what authority? While I readily found a max. input current for the DMT556T (16 mA according to this [DM556T Full Datasheet/user manual](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/download/DM556T.pdf), `4-5 V when HIGH, 0-0.5 V when LOW` is an unusual logic level - optocoupler? I did not find *any* output specification for the DDCS V4.1. ±20 V is pretty high for an OpAmp and uncalled for to meet the levels called for; and not all are ready to deliver 16 mA - or 33.

Comment: Whoever recommended the op-amp buffer solution to me wasn't so sure of his advice.
The basic idea is that a buffer op-amp is one of the few electronic devices that takes an input signal and duplicates it at the output with the same characteristics.
However, do you recommend using a buffer op-amp?

Comment: Questo il link del manuale del DDCS v4.1

https://www.nvcnc.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/DDCS-V4.1-Users-manual-in-English-V1-.pdf